# Why does grunt not work when installed globally?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, gruntjs

I have installed `grunt` and `grunt-cli` globally using `sudo npm install -g grunt...` commands.

My working folder is `/opt/web', please don't ask why :)

Checking grunt version inside `/opt/web' works:

```
$ grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.13
```

However, I can't actually run a grunt task from there:

```
$ grunt
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project.
```

If I install grunt locally, it then asks to install all it's dependencies locally (that are already installed globally (!)).

This behavior seems strange to me.

**My question is**:

Is this a bug or a feature? Is this by design that grunt wants to work with locally installed things only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. See the [grunt-cli readme](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/README.md).

The cli doesn't do anything except find and run a local copy of grunt.

This means that each project can use a version of grunt that the project specifies and is know/tested to work correctly. Given the number of critical things grunt can do, this compatibility promise is a big deal.

There is also a [good blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation) on the node site that talks a bit more about module installation locations.